# View Exception when stopped on Exception Thrown

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

Ok, potentially dumb question, but I don't have the answer:

In Visual Studio 2015, they redid the tooling for the Exception Settings window.  I'm debugging, and I set the "break when thrown" option (I need to break regardless of whether the exception is handled farther up the stack)

No problem getting it to break.  I get a dialog that gives me the option to break or continue.  If I click "break", it stops right where I need it to, but I would really like to examine the exception object.  I don't see a way to gain access to it, unless I F10 or F11 up the stack until I get to the exception handler.  Is there a way to pull up the exception details (like even get the Exception Assistant to pop up, like it does when you break on an unhandled exception?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are debugging C# (Managed Only) and the exception is thrown from Managed code, then yes.

*Normally*, the Exception Assistant will pop up for the exception. If it doesn't, you can check to see if it is enabled in Debug->Options. Additionally, once you break on the exception ("break when thrown"), a pseudo variable representing the exception object will appear in the Locals window called $exception. This is essentially the same exception object that you would see in the Exception Assistant.

Otherwise, you will have to inspect the exception object captured in the debuggee code (such as in a catch handler).